# Regarding random function in asp.net c#

Tags: asp.net

Hi
i want random no. of questions. For that i used random function in asp.net but questions gets repeating.
How i can get non repeated questions.
C#.
Thank you.

Comment: you have to provide some code for your randomizer function in order to get some good answers.

Comment: Random rnd = new Random(); int i = rnd.Next(1, 5); //5 is no of questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with Random is very often the following:

The following code will very often return a very 'non-random' sequence of numbers

```
        for(int j = 0; j<100; j++)
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();      
            int i = rnd.Next(1, 5);
            Console.WriteLine(i);
        }
```

Whereas the following will create a more randomized distribution of numbers:

```
        Random rnd = new Random(); 
        for(int j = 0; j<100; j++)
        {

            int i = rnd.Next(1, 5);
            Console.WriteLine(i);
        }
```

A different approach to generating a random number could be achieved using Linq:

`var randomNumber = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).OrderBy(g => Guid.NewGuid()).First();`

This method first creates a list of numbers (in this example from 1 to 10), and then orders that list by creating a Guid. This shuffles the list so that the First() will be kind of random. I often rely on this method to get a random number instead of using the Random-class.

**UPDATE**

Let's say you want 10 unique random numbers from a list of 100 random numbers. Using the linq-expression you would do:

`List<int> tenRandomNumbers = Enumerable.Range(1, 100).OrderBy(g => Guid.NewGuid()).Take(10);`

Now you should be able to go through the list of `tenRandomNumbers` .. They should be unique and random.

**UPDATE 2**

Take a look at this explanation of the .Take(int) method:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336757#TakeSimple

The code above will return a list of 10 numbers selected randomly from a collection of 100 numbers. What you want to do next is simply:

```
foreach(int i in tenRandomNumbers){
   // code to fetch your question based on int i
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I have tried with this code " var randomNumber = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).OrderBy(g => Guid.NewGuid()).First(); " but its giving error : Enumerable does not exists

Comment: You probably need to include using System.Linq in your class.

Comment: when i run first time then its getting proper but sometimes questions gets repeated

Comment: This is as much as I can help you without you editing you question and adding more sourcecode to your question. How do you retrieve the questions? What does your list look like etc..

Comment: "var randomNumber = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).OrderBy(g => Guid.NewGuid()).First(); " is this code gives repeated no's? because when i use this code it gives repeated values.

Comment: List<int> tenRandomNumbers = Enumerable.Range(1, 100).OrderBy(g => Guid.NewGuid()).Take(10); In this code, List<int> what does it mean? not getting

Comment: List<int> tenRandomNumbers = Enumerable.Range(1, 100).OrderBy(g => Guid.NewGuid()).Take(10); I used this code : int i =Enumerable.Range(1, 100).OrderBy(g => Guid.NewGuid()).Take(10); but it giving error unable to cast

Comment: New update added to explain the .Take() further. Please read it. You're trying to cast a list of ints to a single int, which of logical reasons wont work.

Comment: give me idea about how i will review questions & answers after clicking submit button